# How can I boot after receiving the error code: [drm:vmw_host_printf [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* Failed to send host message.?

Tags: boot, grub2, virtualbox

I'm running Linux ubuntu-22.04 on VirtualBox (64-bit) on an HP laptop. I'm using multiple software's with ubuntu such as MATLAB and sTAMPS. I've started up ubuntu many times before, and one day when I powered up ubuntu I got the error:

```
/dev/sda3: recovering journal

/dev/sda3: clean, 462738/1605632 files, 541841/514154 blocks

[    2.701550] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)

[    2.877431] [drm:vmw_host_printf [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* Failed to send host log message.
```

I have tried:

-uninstalling and reinstalling ubuntu

-rebooting the VB machine

-decreasing video storage

-changing my graphics controller

-removing and reinstalling the SATA storage hard disk with a different GB storage capacity

-turning off the Windows feature "Windows Hypervisor Platform"

-I tried holding "Shift" while starting up to open GRUB but there was no effect, the GRUB menu didn't open

-turning on the Windows feature "Virtual Machine Platform".

I currently have a virtual size of 89.86 GB. Before I received the error I powered off the machine like I usually do and powered it up like I normally do, so I'm not sure how or why I'm getting this error.